# Wagtail not updating field

Tags: python, python-3.x, wagtail

I am using wagtail and after modifying a field to use `duration` instead of `price`, wagtail still shows the field as `price`.

I've run `makemigrations` and `migration` command and the database column is updated but the wagtail admin still has the old field displayed.

How can I fix it?

```
class InfoPage(Page):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, help_text='title')
    duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='Duration')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('duration')
    ]
```

Comment: Can you check the name of the column in your database? You say you ran the `migration` command but the command is actually `migrate`.

Comment: @tomd sorry migration was a type. i meant migrate. The duration column is in the database.

Comment: Is this in development or production? If the latter, it could be that your templates have cached the label, although this seems unlikely. Can you try restarting the app server?

Comment: @tomd that was exactly what happened. It worked after I restarted the server thanks

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Tushortz! I'll rephrase my question as an answer, in case other people get confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your site in production, it is possible that Django is using the [cached template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader), in which case you will need to restart the app server after running migrations.

Comment: This has been the case for me a few times on different sites. I was using uwsgi, and a `sudo systemctl restart uwsgi` was needed.